# How to escape quotation marks and curly brackets in template string

Tags: angular, escaping, interpolation, backticks

Im trying to change the language of the date-picker dynamically. To do so, I have to change the `locale` value of data-options. My plan is to use a template string to change it, whenever the variable `currentLang` changes. 
The problem is, that I can't escape the string properly.

It is currently looking like this:

```
<div class="flatpickr" data-init="auto" data-options=`{"enableTime": true, "locale" : "${currentLang}", "dateFormat" : "Y-m-d H:i:S" }`>
```

In the end I want the string to look like this:

```
data-options='{"enableTime": true, "locale": "en", "dateFormat": "Y-m-d H:i:S"}'
```

Is this even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be difficult to do in the template. An alternative is to define a getter property in code:

```
currentLang = "en-US";

get options(): string {
  return `{"enableTime": true, "locale": "${this.currentLang}", "dateFormat": "Y-m-d H:i:S"}`;
}
```

And set the attribute with [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding):

```
<div class="flatpickr" data-init="auto" [attr.data-options]="options"></div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mhzx1) for a demo.

Please note that attribute binding can also be used for a string obtained with `JSON.stringify(obj)`, if you prefer to generate the string that way.

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: This looks very promising. To update the options I would use set options, and it would update the template, right?

Comment: If you update `currentLang`, the div attribute should update automatically. You can see it in [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mhzx1).

Comment: Okey I was able to implement it and get it working like in the stackblitz. However It won't update my datepicker (flatpickr). Is the flatpickr not reloading? How can I force the flatpickr to use the new options?

Comment: That is a different question, IMO. You could ask a new question about forcing flatpickr to update.

Comment: Okey, I probably will, Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

You could declare a JSON object in your component's TypeScript and bind it in your HTML.

Comment: I also thought about doing it like that. Sadly, I get an error while binding it. The error says that it is not possible to bind data-options to a div.

Answer (score -1):

**Not sure this meets your requirements or not but How about this?**

**With Template literal**

```js
let el = document.querySelector('div');
let currentLang = 'en';
el.setAttribute('data-options', `{"enableTime": true, "locale" : ${currentLang}, "dateFormat" : "Y-m-d H:i:S"}`);
console.log(el);
```

```html
<div class="flatpickr" data-init="auto">
```

**OR** with `JSON.stringify()`

```js
let el = document.querySelector('div');
let currentLang = 'en';
let options = {
  "enableTime": true,
  "local": currentLang,
  "dateFormat": "Y-m-d H:i:S"
}
el.setAttribute('data-options', JSON.stringify(options));
console.log(el);
```

```html
<div class="flatpickr" data-init="auto">
```

Comment: Since I am using it in Angular, I think it's not that easy to do it like that, because I can't bind it to the typescript code.

Comment: @Fabioha ohh , actually I don't know angular :( but straight forward vanilla js seems like this way

Comment: Too bad:(, maybe I can mix both. I will keep it in mind.